# How to align the navbar items to right corner in tailwind

Tags: alignment, navbar, tailwind-css, items

```
<div class="flex md:flex md:flex-grow flex-row-reverse space-x-1">
  <a href="" class="py-4 px-2 text-teal-500 border-b-4 border-teal-300 font-semibold">Home</a>
  <a href="" class="py-4 px-2 text-gray-500 font-semibold hover:text-teal-300 transition duration-300">Services</a>
  <a href="" class="py-4 px-2 text-gray-500 font-semibold hover:text-teal-300 transition duration-300">About</a>
  <a href="" class="py-4 px-2 text-gray-500 font-semibold hover:text-teal-300 transition duration-300">Contact Us</a>
</div>
```

What changes need to be made?

Answer (score 5):

To align your item to the right, you need to justify your flex items to the end by using `justify-end` inside your flex container.

You can also align your nav-bar items to the right side by changing `flex-row` to `flex-row-reverse`. This way, you get both variations of the items' order.

Code:

```js
<div class="flex md:flex md:flex-grow flex-row justify-end space-x-1">
  <a href="" class="py-4 px-2 text-teal-500 border-b-4 border-teal-300 font-semibold">Home</a>
  <a href="" class="py-4 px-2 text-gray-500 font-semibold hover:text-teal-300 transition duration-300">Services</a>
  <a href="" class="py-4 px-2 text-gray-500 font-semibold hover:text-teal-300 transition duration-300">About</a>
  <a href="" class="py-4 px-2 text-gray-500 font-semibold hover:text-teal-300 transition duration-300">Contact Us</a>
</div>

<!-- or -->

<div class="flex md:flex md:flex-grow flex-row-reverse space-x-1">
  <a href="" class="py-4 px-2 text-teal-500 border-b-4 border-teal-300 font-semibold">Home</a>
  <a href="" class="py-4 px-2 text-gray-500 font-semibold hover:text-teal-300 transition duration-300">Services</a>
  <a href="" class="py-4 px-2 text-gray-500 font-semibold hover:text-teal-300 transition duration-300">About</a>
  <a href="" class="py-4 px-2 text-gray-500 font-semibold hover:text-teal-300 transition duration-300">Contact Us</a>
</div>
```

Tailwind-play:
[justify-end](https://play.tailwindcss.com/rTSuCjgxCp), [flex-row-reverse](https://play.tailwindcss.com/HZ6wHilxcY).